# Basis, polynomial vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the vector space $P_3(R)$, find a basis for it containing the polynomials $x^2 + 1$ and $x^2 - 1$.

To find a basis, I need to find whether there exists constants in front of these two vectors that can span ${(1,x,x^2)}?$ What if these two vectors do not span? How would I find a 3rd constant for a 3rd unknown vector? Wouldn't that have too many variables?

Similarly, determine whether B = $ (1-x, 2-3x^2, x+2x^2) $ is a basis for $P_2(R)$.

For that, is it intuitive that B cannot be a basis, since $P_2$ only has 2 vectors and B has 3?

Comment: What is the vector space $P_3(R)$?

Comment: Sorry brain fart, it is the polynomial vector $(1,x,x^2,x^3)$

Comment: I think you mean to say it is the vector space spanned by $(1,x,x^2,x^3)$? That is all real polynomials of degree at most 3. Any basis for this space has length 4, and you're given that $x^2+1$ and $x^2-1$ are both basis vectors. You must find 2 other vectors to add to those two so that the list of all of them is linearly independent, and spans the space.

Answer (score 0):

The two polynomials contain $2x^2$ and the constant $2$ obtained respectively as their sum and difference, hence their linear span contain all polynomials of the form $a+cx^2$, and so throwing in the two linearly independent polynomials (imitating the existing ones)  $x^3+x $ and $x^3-x$, should take care of all polynomials of degree 3 or less. It is a basis because we have totally 4 polynomails.